can't download some youtube videos using python pytube library on colab
!pip install pytube
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
from pytube import YouTube
# Replace 'video_url' with the URL of the problematic video
video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdPK6pd6XnA"
yt = YouTube(video_url)
yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download('/content/drive/My Drive')

i tried to download some youtube videos on colab using above code..some were downloaded(they also had sinhala characters in their name like this failed videos) and some were not..when it failed gave this error
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/content/drive/My Drive/සමාධිය අඩු වෙලා වීර්යය වැඩි කරගත්තොත් කලබලකාරී වෙනවා සමාධිය වැඩි වෙලා විර්යය අඩු වුණොත් උදාසීන වෙනවා.mp4'

i tried sanitizing the code with this code
def sanitize_filename(filename):
# Remove any characters that are not allowed in filenames
sanitized_filename = re.sub(r'[<>:"/\\|?*]', '_', filename)
# Trim the filename if it's too long
max_filename_length = 255 # Max filename length for most filesystems
if len(sanitized_filename) > max_filename_length:
sanitized_filename = sanitized_filename[:max_filename_length]
return sanitized_filename

but it also failed..how can i download the same video with pytube..or if can't with another library..this is the video i mentioned.. https://youtu.be/HdPK6pd6XnA

The issue here appears to be encoding-related (the underlying OS used by Colab cannot handle those Sinhala characters in file names). Manually name the downloaded videos using ASCII characters and you should be fine.

@Dan but some videos with sinhala characters downloaded with the same code..

It's hard to diagnose further without the full traceback and knowing which specific line of code it occurred in, what happens in your sanitized code (same error?), etc.

@Dan yes sanatized code also gives the same error.. error occurs in the last line..when i midified it as yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download('/content/drive/My Drive', filename='something.mp3') file downloaded without any error..it means error is with file name..

@Dan yes error comes with the sanitized code also and it occurs in the last line of the code.. when i edited it as yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download('/content/drive/My Drive', filename='something.mp3')
file downloaded without any error..but i need to download it with the original name..

The traceback shows the error is from the operating system (OS). If changing the filename fixed it, almost certainly there is some character in the filename the OS cannot handle. If you need to retain the title, consider storing it in some metadata file. You could also use a library like moviepy and alter the video file metadata itself to include the title (see, e.g., https://devcodef1.com/news/1022421/edit-video-metadata-with-python ).
